# How g_main_loop works in gtk programming?

Tags: c, event-handling, gtk, glib

I am new to GTK+ programming. I came across an API called `g_main_loop()`. I have used it in my code but I am still unaware that how exactly it works. Can somebody explain `g_main_loop()` with small code snippet?

Comment: It's quite simple to use as you probably know. Here is how event loops work in general: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend [reading the documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.description), starting with the linked-to function `g_main_loop_new()`.

Basically, letting glib "own" your application's main loop makes it easier to support things like "pluggable" event sources; where your application listens to both (for example) events coming from GTK+ widgets, and a network socket or Unix pipe. These are things that need to be hooked together at a fairly low level in an application's main loop, and letting glib own those parts makes it easier.

There are glib data structures (like [IO channels](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-IO-Channels.html)) that are compatible with the main loop and allow you to add things to the set of inputs the loop manages. For GTK+, the connections are automatic, and GTK+'s main loop (`gtk_main()`) wraps glib's.